# Permutations and combinations- reverse gap method

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that there are 10 people sitting in a row. Their positions are fixed and each person is distinct. Now we need to find the number of ways of selecting any 4 non-consecutive people.

I didn't really understand the way our sir explained this problem in class. But taking the jist of what he did, I made my own logic.

If we take out 4 non-consecutive people, the number of people left is 6. Now the number of possible arrangements of 6 identical and 4 identical (but different than those 6) things in a row such that no two of the 4 identical things can be consecutive is 7C4 (by gap method). Another way to understand this- take 4 A's and 6 B's. Arrangement of these such that no two A are consecutive is 7C4.

Similarly we can tag 4 people as 'R' (removed) and 6 as 'N' (non-removed) and arrange them. So such arrangements will be 7C4 (considering that the only distinctness between people is their tags) . And each arrangement corresponds to only one way of selecting 4 non-consecutive people in our original row of 10 people as the position of each person is fixed. So our final answer is 7C4.

Our sir called this 'reverse gap method' but I can't find any mention of a method with such a name on any site. I know, this problem can be done by stars and bars method too. But I just want to know if this line of logic I mentioned above is completely foolproof or not?

Comment: Clarification requested: "Now we need to find the number of ways of selecting any 4 non-consecutive people." Are the people in seats 1,2,3,5 considered non-consecutive.  If so, the easy approach is to ask [1] how many ways there are of selecting 4 people? [2] Of those selections, how many involve 4 *consecutive people*?

Comment: Re previous comment, if the people in seats 1,2,3,5 **are** construed to constitute 4 consecutive people, then the problem is still easy.  You simply have to manually identify all the selections of 4 people that do not include any two people *next to each other*.  Under this interpretation, since $(10)$ is such a small number, a viable approach is to take your shoes off and count.

Comment: @user2661923-  1,2,3,5 are considered consecutive. No two people can be next to each other. There must be a gap of atleast one person between any two people. And I already know that we can manually calculate it. But that's not the point. What if there are a large number of people? There are many ways to do it, I know that. My question is whether my logic mentioned above is correct or not?

Comment: Very good reply.

Comment: @user2661923- Thank you

Comment: For what it's worth, I was unable to follow your logic.  However, I came to the same answer through [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/), since the problem analogizes to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = (10 - 4) = 6 ~: x_1, x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},$ and $~x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$  This *bijects* to $x_1 + \cdots + x_5 = 3 ~: x_1, \cdots, x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$  This bijected equation has $$\binom{3 + [5-1]}{[5-1]} = \binom{7}{4} ~\text{solutions}.$$

Comment: If you have made your own logic, how can we understand and explain what is the *reverses gap* method ?  I have heard of the "string" method and the "gap" method examples of which you can see at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464822/gap-and-string-method-in-permutations-and-combinations

Comment: @user2661923- yup stars and bars is so clear and straightforward. Maybe I should just stick to that way. I don't think anyone is going to understand this logic anyway. I did try my best to put it forward but maybe I've not explained clearly enough.